# itextsharp 5.4.4 - GetDrawingImage decodes this image the wrong way - why?

Tags: image, pdf, itext, extract

This [pdf](https://anonfiles.com/file/978e5ff1adff1ce2e95e01552c45bea3) is displayed on my Firefox very well but in a `C#` program I wrote using `itextsharp` 5.4.4, I used the `GetDrawingImage` method of the `PdfImageObject` and I get a grabled image.

I used itextsharp in the following way:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
ImageRenderListener listener = new ImageRenderListener();
parser.ProcessContent(pageNumber, listener);
```

Where `ImageRenderListener` is a `IRenderListener`, which implements the `RenderImage` method in the following way:

```
    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();

        PdfObject obj = image.Get(PdfName.FILTER);

        PdfName filter = null;

        if (obj is PdfName)
        {
            filter = (PdfName)obj;
        }
        else if (obj is PdfArray)
        {
            foreach(var o in (PdfArray)obj)
            {
                if (o is PdfName)
                {
                    filter = o as PdfName;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image drawingImage = image.GetDrawingImage();
...
...
...
        }
```

The drawing image is stored in the listener and then drawn to the screen etc...

I tried to understand this, I get that the filter is a `/CCITTFaxDecode` but the `streamContentType` is somehow a `png`, could someone enlighten me on this matter?

Comment: *the `filter` is a **/CCITTFaxDecode** but the `streamContentType` is somehow a **png*** - an iText image extraction result *will either be a png or a tiff, depending on the color depth of the image,* cf. the documentation of `PdfImageObject.decodeImageBytes`; that being said, there seems to be an issue in iText (or the image data) as the png result for your PDF looks broken in my test setup.

Comment: @mkl thanx for the explanation, anyway my intention was to ask why iTextSharp make this PDF look broken, when with other tools it looks just fine...

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this problem is explained in the following video: [Ripping your PDF files apart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iCln0doF88). If you don't want to sit through the complete video, fast forward to minute 24 and watch everything up onto minute 27. Note the conclusion on minute 27: *In general, there are no images in PDF.* (That's exaggerated, but if you understand the 3 minutes of explanation, you understand what Mark Stephens means.)

If you want the details about why CCITTFaxDecode is changed into PNG, please read chapter 10 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

Comment: This talk was very helpful in understanding images in PDF is a indeed a complex subject (and yes there are no images :-)), but I still don't understand why the example PDF I gave looks broken in iText...

Comment: Well I have tried to dig in the code of iTextSharp to find why this is happenning, so far I could not find why, I suspect a bug in the decoding of 1D T4, I have by passed this for now, with the help of the `TiffWriter` class for this case only, I would really want to find out but my time is limited... thank you anyway for this greate library...

Comment: Thanks too for that powerful lib. 
And I have similar problem with /CCITTTFAXDECODE images. I compress them up 2 times (as *.png, using FreeImage lib), save it to filesystem and check. But when I'm going to insert back to PDF compressed image with stamper.Writer.AddDirectImageSimple() (and called KillInderect() before), the resulting compressed PDF file remains almost the same size. I debugged ITextSharp sourcecode by the way and still could not find the root cause...